# why having a long buffer is a disadvantage?

Tags: networking

well its always preferred that buffers should be as large as possible in networking.

but can having a very large buffer or a long buffer be a disadvantage?

Answer (score 2):

A downside to larger buffers is that they can cause the appearance of "lag," because the buffer has to hit a high water mark before it gets sent.  I would not say "it's always preferred."

Answer (score 2):

A recent posting about possible causes of a certain wireless carriers issues covers this in great detail. It's a good read and answers this pretty clearly:

http://blogs.broughturner.com/2009/10/is-att-wireless-data-congestion-selfinflicted.html